# Coredns in Crashloopbackoff state with calico network

Tags: kubernetes, calico, coredns

I have a ubuntu 16.04 running in virtual box. I installed Kubernetes on it as a single node using kubeadm.

But coredns pods are in Crashloopbackoff state.

All other pods are running.

Single interface(enp0s3) - Bridge Network

Applied calico using
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml

```yaml
output on kubectl describe pod: 
 Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  41m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-66bff467f8-dxzq7 to kube
  Normal   Pulled     39m (x5 over 41m)    kubelet, kube      Container image "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    39m (x5 over 41m)    kubelet, kube      Created container coredns
  Normal   Started    39m (x5 over 41m)    kubelet, kube      Started container coredns
  Warning  BackOff    87s (x194 over 41m)  kubelet, kube      Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: What do the logs say? `kubectl logs <coredns-pod>`

Comment: root@kube:/home/kube# kubectl logs coredns-66bff467f8-dxzq7 -n kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7
CoreDNS-1.6.7
linux/amd64, go1.13.6, da7f65b
[FATAL] plugin/loop: Loop (127.0.0.1:34536 -> :53) detected for zone ".", see https://coredns.io/plugins/loop#troubleshooting. Query: "HINFO 8322382447049308542.5528484581440387393."
root@kube:/home/kube#

Comment: @NitishGoel please add full log

Comment: Is your calico pod up?

Comment: Issue is solved now, after pointing resolv.cinf in kubelet config file and removed loopback ip from resolv.conf. Thanks

Comment: @Nitish Goel please elaborate your solution and post it as an answer. It might help other with similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did a `kubectl logs <coredns-pod>` and found error logs below and looked in the mentioned [link](https://coredns.io/plugins/loop/#troubleshooting)
As per suggestion, added `resolv.conf = /etc/resolv.conf` at the end of `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet/conf.yaml` and recreated the pod.

```
kubectl logs coredns-66bff467f8-dxzq7 -n kube-system 
.:53 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7 CoreDNS-1.6.7 linux/amd64, go1.13.6, da7f65b [FATAL] plugin/loop: Loop (127.0.0.1:34536 -> :53) detected for zone ".", see coredns.io/plugins/loop#troubleshooting. Query: "HINFO 8322382447049308542.5528484581440387393." 
root@kube:/home/kube#
```

Answer (score 0):

Commented below line in /etc/resolv.conf (Host machine) and delete the coredns pods in kube-system namespace. 
New pods came in running state :)

- #nameserver 127.0.1.1